# Thread-safely transforming a value in a mutable map

Tags: scala, dictionary, concurrency, thread-safety

Suppose I want to use a mutable map in Scala to keep track of the number of times I've seen some strings. In a single-threaded context, this is easy:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.{ Map => MMap }

class Counter {
  val counts = MMap.empty[String, Int].withDefaultValue(0)

  def add(s: String): Unit = counts(s) += 1
}
```

Unfortunately this isn't thread-safe, since the `get` and the `update` don't happen atomically.

[Concurrent maps](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.concurrent.Map) add [a few atomic operations](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/concrete-mutable-collection-classes.html#concurrent_maps) to the mutable map API, but not the one I need, which would look something like this:

```
def replace(k: A, f: B => B): Option[B]
```

I know I can use [ScalaSTM](http://nbronson.github.io/scala-stm/api/0.7/index.html#scala.concurrent.stm.TMap)'s [`TMap`](http://nbronson.github.io/scala-stm/api/0.7/index.html#scala.concurrent.stm.TMap):

```
import scala.concurrent.stm._

class Counter {
  val counts =  TMap.empty[String, Int]

  def add(s: String): Unit = atomic { implicit txn =>
    counts(s) = counts.get(s).getOrElse(0) + 1
  }
}
```

But (for now) that's still an extra dependency. Other options would include actors (another dependency), synchronization (potentially less efficient), or Java's [atomic references](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html) ([less idiomatic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6869807/334519)).

In general I'd avoid mutable maps in Scala, but I've occasionally needed this kind of thing, and most recently I've used the STM approach (instead of just crossing my fingers and hoping I don't get bitten by the naïve solution).

I know there are a number of trade-offs here (extra dependencies vs. performance vs. clarity, etc.), but is there anything like a "right" answer to this problem in Scala 2.10?

Comment: what about a single Akka actor that writes to the mutable map? `Counter.add` just sends a fire-and-forget message to it. As for reads, depending on your needs they can happen concurrently or go through the actor too.

Answer (score 10):

How about this one? Assuming you don't really need a general `replace` method right now, just a counter.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger

object CountedMap {
  private val counts = new ConcurrentHashMap[String, AtomicInteger]

  def add(key: String): Int = {
    val zero = new AtomicInteger(0)
    val value = Option(counts.putIfAbsent(key, zero)).getOrElse(zero)
    value.incrementAndGet
  }
}
```

You get better performance than synchronizing on the whole map, and you also get atomic increments.

Comment: Thanks—I am interested in the general case, but it's good to see that this is so easy.

Comment: This is the right solution and leverages the very high performance Java concurrent libraries.

Comment: I'm curious if there's a reason to reach for ConcurrentHashMap instead of concurrent.TrieMap. I have no opinion, just that the forum is an ad for API.

Comment: @som-snytt I was not aware of that class, and I don't have an opinion right now in choosing one or the other.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution is definitely synchronization. If there is not too much contention, performance might not be that bad.

Otherwise, you could try to roll up your own STM-like `replace` implementation. Something like this might do:

```
object ConcurrentMapOps {
  private val rng = new util.Random
  private val MaxReplaceRetryCount = 10
  private val MinReplaceBackoffTime: Long = 1
  private val MaxReplaceBackoffTime: Long = 20
}
implicit class ConcurrentMapOps[A, B]( val m: collection.concurrent.Map[A,B] ) {
  import ConcurrentMapOps._
  private def replaceBackoff() {
    Thread.sleep( (MinReplaceBackoffTime + rng.nextFloat * (MaxReplaceBackoffTime - MinReplaceBackoffTime) ).toLong ) // A bit crude, I know
  }

  def replace(k: A, f: B => B): Option[B] = {
    m.get( k ) match {
      case None => return None
      case Some( old ) =>
        var retryCount = 0
        while ( retryCount <= MaxReplaceRetryCount ) {
          val done = m.replace( k, old, f( old ) )
          if ( done ) {
            return Some( old )
          }
          else {         
            retryCount += 1
            replaceBackoff()
          }
        }
        sys.error("Could not concurrently modify map")
    }
  }
}
```

Note that collision issues are localized to a given key. If two threads access the same map but work on distinct keys, you'll have no collisions and the replace operation will always succeed the first time. If a collision is detected, we wait a bit (a random amount of time, so as to minimize the likeliness of threads fighting forever for the same key) and try again.

I cannot guarantee that this is production-ready (I just tossed it right now), but that might do the trick.

**UPDATE**: Of course (as Ionuț G. Stan pointed out), if all you want is increment/decrement a value, java's `ConcurrentHashMap` already provides thoses operations in a lock-free manner. 
My above solution applies if you need a more general `replace` method that would take the transformation function as a parameter.

Comment: I noticed in the Map code he switched to ThreadLocalRandom https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/library/scala/collection/concurrent/TrieMap.scala#L473

Answer (score 2):

You're asking for trouble if your map is just sitting there as a val.  If it meets your use case, I'd recommend something like

```
class Counter {
  private[this] myCounts = MMap.empty[String, Int].withDefaultValue(0)
  def counts(s: String) = myCounts.synchronized { myCounts(s) }
  def add(s: String) = myCounts.synchronized { myCounts(s) += 1 }
  def getCounts = myCounts.synchronized { Map[String,Int]() ++ myCounts }
}
```

for low-contention usage.  For high-contention, you should use a concurrent map designed to support such use (e.g. `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap`) and wrap the values in `AtomicWhatever`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are ok to work with future based interface:

```
trait SingleThreadedExecutionContext {
  val ec = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())
}

class Counter extends SingleThreadedExecutionContext {
  private val counts = MMap.empty[String, Int].withDefaultValue(0)

  def get(s: String): Future[Int] = future(counts(s))(ec)

  def add(s: String): Future[Unit] = future(counts(s) += 1)(ec)
}
```

Test will look like:

```
class MutableMapSpec extends Specification {

  "thread safe" in {

    import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

    val c = new Counter
    val testData = Seq.fill(16)("1")
    await(Future.traverse(testData)(c.add))
    await(c.get("1")) mustEqual 16
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not thread safe at all. While you guarantee a single writer at a time, you can still have threads reading while the map is being modified

Comment: As I understand, all operations - read, write, mixed - that use ec as context will be thread safe. Ops outside that context will not be thread-safe. Will be glad to hear from others if this understanding is correct.

Comment: But the thing is, the reading is done directly: when you access `c.counts` you are not using the `ExecutionContext` at all.

Comment: c.counts is a mutable map so exposing it to the outside world is not a good idea. I updated the code by adding a get method and making map private. The gist is: all read/write to the mutable map must be guarded by ec. If that is not acceptable, use a concurrent data structure.

Comment: Yes, that was my whole point. This is much better now. Actually if OP can indeed adapt his code to use futures, this is the best solution in terms of ease of use and correctness (though not iintterms of speed).

Comment: I'm not sure I'd want to dedicate a thread to one counter, but maybe if it was doing other drudge work; a get could wait in a long queue. But if hourly rates correlate with SO rep, this is a great deal. Also satisfies the no-dependency requirement, if Akka is a dependency.

Comment: Of course if this is literaly just to perform increments, this is overkill. For something more substantial in terms of computation, that is a nice enough solution. A fully generic solution would actually use a fixed set of one-thread pools (a pool of thread pools) and just make sure that each instance of the map always uses the same one-threa pool. This would prevent the thread count from explosing (as the number of maps grow) while still ensuring that there is no thread-unsafe access.

Comment: @RégisJean-Gilles Yes. I +1 this + yours, which I mashed up to some effect below, for some value of some.