# Best practices for mixing in Scala concurrent.Map

Tags: scala, concurrency, hashmap

The [ScalaDoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.ConcurrentMap) says this about concurrentMap: "Deprecated (Since version 2.10.0) Use `scala.collection.concurrent.Map` instead." Unfortunately, the [rest of the Scala docs](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/concrete-mutable-collection-classes.html#concurrent_maps) has not been updated and still references `concurrentMap`.

I tried to mix in `concurrent.Map` into a `HashMap`, with the following results:

```
scala> val mmap = new mutable.HashMap[String, String] with collection.concurrent.Map[String, String]
<console>:16: error: object creation impossible, since:
it has 4 unimplemented members.
/** As seen from anonymous class $anon, the missing signatures are as follows.
 *  For convenience, these are usable as stub implementations.
 */
  def putIfAbsent(k: String,v: String): Option[String] = ???
  def remove(k: String,v: String): Boolean = ???
  def replace(k: String,v: String): Option[String] = ???
  def replace(k: String,oldvalue: String,newvalue: String): Boolean = ???

       val mmap = new mutable.HashMap[String, String] with collection.concurrent.Map[String, String]
```

So we see that instead of a simple mixin, some methods must also be implemented. Is this the best way to use `concurrent.Map`, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The `scala.collection.concurrent.Map` trait is *not meant to be mixed-in* with an existing mutable Scala `Map` to obtain a thread-safe version of the map instance. The `SynchronizedMap` mixin existed for this purpose before `2.11`, but is now deprecated.

Currently, Scala has the `scala.collection.concurrent.TrieMap` implementation for the `scala.collection.concurrent.Map` interface, but can wrap Java classes as well.

The `scala.collection.concurrent.Map`, in versions prior to 2.10 known as `scala.collection.mutable.ConcurrentMap`, interface is used when you:

- want to implement your own concurrent, thread-safe `Map` from scratch
- want to wrap an existing Java concurrent map implementation:

E.g:

```
import scala.collection._
import scala.collection.convert.decorateAsScala._
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap

val map: concurrent.Map[String, String] = new ConcurrentHashMap().asScala
```

- want to write generic code that works concurrent maps, and don't want to commit to a specific implementation:

E.g.:

```
import scala.collection._

def foo(map: concurrent.Map[String, String]) = map.putIfAbsent("", "")

foo(new concurrent.TrieMap)
foo(new java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap().asScala)
```

- you could implement your own wrapper around a single-threaded mutable map implementation by using synchronized (but you would need to ensure that your program is accessing the mutable map only through this wrapper and never directly).

E.g.:

```
class MySynchronizedMap[K, V](private val underlying: mutable.Map[K, V])
extends concurrent.Map[K, V] {
  private val monitor = new AnyRef
  def putIfAbsent(k: K,v: V): Option[String] = monitor.synchronized {
    underlying.get(k) match {
      case s: Some[V] => s
      case None =>
        underlying(k) = v
        None
    }
  }
  def remove(k: K, v: V): Boolean = monitor.synchronized {
    underlying.get(k) match {
      case Some(v0) if v == v0 => underlying.remove(k); true
      case None => false
    }
  }
  // etc.
}
```

Comment: Scala 2.11 deprecates the synchronized traits

Comment: scala.collection.mutable.ConcurrentMap is also deprecated in favor of scala.collection.concurrent.Map; making this change messes up the remainder of the solution

Comment: Could you explain? You could just replace `ConcurrentMap` with `concurrent.Map` in the examples above, no?

Comment: I'm the author of both `ConcurrentMap` and the `concurrent.Map` trait, and I'm pretty sure it does work. Maybe there's some typo in the code above, but unless you tell me more about what doesn't work, I cannot help :(

Comment: IntelliJ's presentation compiler complains about foo(new java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap().asScala) however SBT compiles and runs without complaint.

Comment: Other than the fact that the real bug fix for https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7943 will come 3 years later in  https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9147. Sheesh .... (banging my head).

Comment: Since 2.12 we should use `import scala.collection.JavaConverters._`, `scala.collection.convert.decorateAsScala._` is deprecated

Answer (score 16):

Unless you want to implement a concurrent mutable hash map yourself, you have to use `scala.collection.concurrent.TrieMap`.

Comment: What about concurrent HashSet and WeakHashMap?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 10):

Taken from this comment directly: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49689669/7082628

In 2018, apparently you can just do this:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap

val m: ConcurrentHashMap[String,MyClass] = new ConcurrentHashMap
```

Answer (score 3):

By "simple mixin", perhaps you're asking if the trait can be used as a decorator [as shown here](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/collections.html#lst:synchronized-map) for [`SynchronizedMap`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.SynchronizedMap), and the answer is apparently not.

Implementations include `TrieMap` and the wrapper for Java's `ConcurrentMap` (of which there are two implementations). (Java also offers `ConcurrentSkipListSet` as Set.)

Also see [this roll-your-own question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18149133/1296806).

They have you covered on the conversion side of things, if that's what you were used to:

```
scala> import java.util.concurrent._
import java.util.concurrent._

scala> import collection.JavaConverters._
import collection.JavaConverters._

scala> val m = new ConcurrentHashMap[String, Int]
m: java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap[String,Int] = {}

scala> val mm = m.asScala
mm: scala.collection.concurrent.Map[String,Int] = Map()

scala> mm.replace("five",5)
res0: Option[Int] = None

scala> mm.getClass
res1: Class[_ <: scala.collection.concurrent.Map[String,Int]] = class scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JConcurrentMapWrapper
```

Comment: I've seen this example written with infix notation elsewhere. What about concurrent versions of HashSet and WeakHashMap? Have they been implemented or is there a way to mix in behavior into the single-threaded version? I'd prefer to synchronize on individual keys, not synchronize the entire collection

Answer (score 3):

Update for 2021 and Scala 2.13:

You need to use different implicit conversion when wrapping the Java concurrent map implementation:

```scala
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap
import scala.collection.concurrent
import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._

val map: concurrent.Map[String, String] = new ConcurrentHashMap().asScala
```