# What's the difference between scala TrieMap and Java ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: scala

It says that scala TrieMap will produce a `consistent` iterator when iterating over the TrieMap, I don't understand what `consistent` here really means.

I need an collection to build an object pools,  that is, objects in the pool will be borrowed/released concurrently, and in the meanwhile, a scheduled thread will iterate over this collection,and check whether there are stale objects, if there is, then create a new one and delete the stale one from the collection.

I am evaluating whether scala TrieMap can be used as the pool.

Also, can someone show some code to illustrate the difference between `scala TrieMap` and `Java ConcurrentHashMap`?

Comment: > I don't understand what consistent here really means.
The following question has details on 'consistent' iterator:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29499381/what-is-a-triemap-and-what-is-its-advantages-disadvantages-compared-to-a-hashmap

Comment: A consistent iterator means that it will be able to provide a snapshot of the `TrieMap` at the point you request a snapshot, or an iterator. If you read the guarantee you get from `ConcurrentHashMap`, it says: *Iterators and Enumerations return elements reflecting the state of the hash table **at some point at or since the creation of the iterator/enumeration***, which I'm not sure is what you want. Also, iterators over `TrieMap` should be very fast to retrieve (O(1)).

Answer (score 3):

One difference between the two I came across is that `TrieMap.getOrElseUpdate` may run the supplied operation multiple times (though at most once per thread calling it) but `ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent` does some locking to make sure it only runs once across all threads.

You can try the following code:

```
(0 to 1000) map { _ =>
  Future { 
    Thread.sleep(100)
    map.getOrElseUpdate(1, {
      Thread.sleep(100)
      counter.incrementAndGet()
    }) 
  }
}
```

and the counter is most probably not 1, but when tried with `concurrentHashMap` it is 1.

Comment: I think this changed in version 2.11.6. According to docs: "Note: This method will invoke op at most once...."
see: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.6/index.html#scala.collection.concurrent.TrieMap

Comment: Both methods are atomic and doing the same job:
putIfAbsent and getOrElseUpdate

Comment: @fonkap your link is outdated, here is a better one: https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/4319