# What would be a scenario when you would use a Hashmap over a Triemap?

Tags: java, data-structures

To me it seems like a Triemap saves memory compared to a Hashmap and can be used in all the scenarios a Hashmap is used. Why would you use a hashmap?

Comment: I am not aware of any TrieMaps in Java. Are you confusing this with Scala perhaps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29499381/what-is-a-triemap-and-what-is-its-advantages-disadvantages-compared-to-a-hashmap

Comment: Java doesn't have a Triemap!